# Экранирование спецсимволов

Tags: python-3.x, pymysql

Есть в БД текстовое поле со значением "аааа\nббббб".
При чтении из базы я получаю эту строку в виде `"аааа\\nббббб"`. Как сделать так, чтобы не происходило экранирования спецсимволов?

Comment: «получаю эту строку» — где и как конкретно получаете?

Comment: Подозреваю, что '\\' вы видите только в отладчике. при печати будет снова  `аааа\nббббб`.

Comment: Именно так. Это можно как-то побороть?

Comment: Перестать смотреть отладчик, например?

Comment: Смешно. Мне нужно чтобы этот управляющий символ отрабатывался в выводе, а не экранировался.

Comment: Какой управляющий символ в каком выводе? В показанном вами значении нет управляющих символов

Comment: '\n' - мне нужно чтобы он отработал как перенос строки

Comment: А почему вы вообще записали в базу именно слэш и буковку "n" вместо того, чтобы записать управляющий символ переноса строки и не мучаться теперь?

Comment: В базе строка записана в таком виде, потому что мне далее в программе она нужна с этими управляющими символами, как значение переменной

Comment: Ни слэш, ни буковка n не являются управляющими символами. Если вы хотите, чтобы сочетание слэша и буковки n обозначали какой-то управляющий символ — ну значит выполните соответствующую замену в строке, наверное?

Comment: ` "aaa\\nbbb".encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('unicode_escape') `